# How to get contact details using office.js/outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, office365-apps

is there way to get contacts similar to [micrososft graph api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_contacts#http-request) using outlook add-in with office.js .[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161005.aspx) document is not clear.i am looking something like following

```
Office.context.contacts  ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Office.Contact interface represents a contact which is stored on the server. It is read mode only.

The list of contacts associated with an email message or appointment is returned in the contacts property of the [Office.Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/outlook_1_6/office.entities?view=office-js) object that is returned by the getEntities or getEntitiesByType method of the active item.

For more information, please review the following link: [Office.Contact interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/outlook_1_6/office.contact?view=office-js)